# Why is my program to convert a decimal number to a binary number not working?

Tags: c, binary

I'm trying to convert a decimal number, using C, and my function is doing the first part right, but not the second. It's supposed to get the remainder of the number divided by 2, store those numbers in an array, and return the array but reversed. My code is:

```
int* showbits(int decNum){
    int originalBits[32];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        int temp = decNum % 2;
        originalBits[i] = temp;
        decNum = decNum / 2;
    }
        int a;
    for (a = 0; a < 32; a++){
        printf("%d ", originalBits[a]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    int j = 0;
    int k = 32;
    int bits[32];
    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++){
        for (k = 32; k > 0; k--){
            bits[j] = originalBits[k];
        }
    }

    int m;
    for (m = 0; m < 32; m++){
        printf("%d ", bits[m]);
    }

    return bits;
}
```

The output puts all 1s if I feed the function 255. I also tried replacing the last loop with:

```
    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++){

            bits[j] = originalBits[k--];

    }
```

but this misses a number and for 255, gives 1111111 instead of 11111111

Comment: Apart from your wrong bits, you return the address of a local variable with non-static lifetime. This will crash sooner or later.

Comment: @Gerhardh I thought you can't return an array; you can only return a pointer.

Comment: That does not change the lifetime of `int bits[32];`. You need a variable with static duration or use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Gerhardh how would this function look if I did that? the output needs to have 32 bits

Comment: If you handle bits, why do you use integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not make sense at all:

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++)
{
    for (k = 32; k > 0; k--)
    {
        bits[j] = originalBits[k];
    }
}
```

I think you want to reverese here, but think about what you are doing.
You are using one loop iteration of `j` to write every element of `originalBits` to `bits[0]` then you do the same to `bits[1]` and continue on. This means at the end every value of bits has the value of `originalBits[0]`.

One loop is sufficent here, you just have to start reading from the otherside of the array:

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++)
{
    bits[j] = originalBits[31-j];
}
```

This way you read from the end of `originalBits` to the front and write to the front of `bits` to the end. Enough to reverse the content.

Other than that you can not return a pointer to an array that is local to the function.

```
int bits[32];
```

will be invalid as soon as you reach the end of the function, yet you pass the address of it to the caller. This is undefined behaviour and has tobe avoided.

Either you create an array with static storage duration, for example by declaring it in file scope as a global variable.

Or you could use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) to get memory dynamically,

```
int *bits = malloc(32 * sizeof *bits);
```

but the you have to make sure you also free the allocated memory.

Another possibility would be declaring the array in `main` and passing the address to the function then you would be able to write to it and you would not even have to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your version 1:

At the end of your inner loop, `k` is always 0.

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++){
    for (k = 32; k > 0; k--){
         bits[j] = originalBits[k];
     }
 }
```

This means that each `bits[j]` will hold the value of `originalBits[0]` after the nested loops.

Solution:

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++){
   bits[j] = originalBits[31-j];
}
```

Regarding your version 2:

You start with `k=32` and decrement **after** using it in each iteration:

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++){
        bits[j] = originalBits[k--];
}
```

This means you will end up with `originalBits[32]` ... `originalBits[1]` in your array.
This is an out of bounds access and also missing the last element.

A solution would be like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++){
  bits[j] = originalBits[31-j];
}
```

As a general hint:
This type of error can be easily spotted using a debugger. Step through your loops, watch your index variables, fix it.

Update regarding returning pointer to non-static array:

```
int* showbits(int decNum)
{
  int bits[32];
  ...
  return bits;
}
```

Here `bits` will become invalid after the function is left. This makes your pointer invalid.

You can solve this in different ways:

If you function is not called simultanously from multiple threads or for multiple value before the array is used:

```
int* showbits(int decNum)
{
  static int bits[32];
  ...
  return bits;
}
```

Now the array will keep valid and your pointer as well. If you call the function again, the same array is used, changing bits from previous calls.

If you need different buffers:

```
int* showbits(int decNum)
{
  int *bits = malloc(sizeof(*bits)*32);
  ...
  return bits;
}
```

Then you need to `free` the pointer afterwards in the calling function.